# Execute function content in json, for bbcode tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this json

```
var bbCodes = {
    success: {
        replacement: '<div class="success"><p>{ATTR}</p>{CONTENT}</div>'
    },

    warn: {
        replacement: '<div class="warn"><p>{ATTR}</p>{CONTENT}</div>'
    },

    bs: {
        replacement : '<a href="/u1">{CONTENT}</a>',
        replace : function(content) {
            if(content.indexOf('hello') !== -1) {
               return 'You said Hello';
            }
          }
    }
};
```

How to make the (content) of the JSON function is related to what's between the tags ... Example:
`[bs]hello guys[/bs]`

And in content, return what is in JSON function

The rest of the code:

```js
var content = $('.postbody, .blog_message');

$.each(bbCodes, function(tag, value) {
      var re = new RegExp('\\['+tag+'(?:=("|\'?)([^\\]]+)\\1)?\\]([\\s\\S]*?)\\[/'+tag+']', 'gi');
      var a = '$2', b = '$3';
      var replacement = value.replacement.replace(/{ATTR}/g,a).replace(/{CONTENT}/g,b);
      content.html(function() {
          return $(this).html().replace(re, replacement);
      }); // Converting tags
});
```

Comment: I need help here... Someone?